Maven minify is stripping whitespace out of a url string in CSS
We are using minify-maven-plugin to minimize our Javascript and CSS files.  Recently we encountered an error where it is stripping the whitespace out of a URL string which makes it unusable.    This is the configuration were using for the plugin.
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.samaxes.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>minify-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>default-minify</id>
            <configuration>
                <jsEngine>CLOSURE</jsEngine>
                <skipMerge>true</skipMerge>
                <nosuffix>true</nosuffix>
                <webappSourceDir>${basedir}/src/main/webapp</webappSourceDir>
                <cssSourceDir>css</cssSourceDir>
                <cssSourceFiles>
                    <cssSourceFile>global.css</cssSourceFile>
                </cssSourceFiles>
                <jsSourceDir>javascript</jsSourceDir>
                <jsSourceFiles>
                    <jsSourceFile>root.js</jsSourceFile>
                    <jsSourceFile>global.js</jsSourceFile>
                </jsSourceFiles>
            </configuration>
            <goals>
                <goal>minify</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>

This is the line of code that is being impacted:
        background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 14 14'%3e%3ccircle cx='50%25' cy='50%25' r='4' fill='%23EA7200'/%3e%3c/svg%3e");

And this is what it looks like after minify has been run:
        background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3csvgxmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'viewBox='001414'%3e%3ccirclecx='50%25'cy='50%25'r='4'fill='%23EA7200'/%3e%3c/svg%3e")

Any help on how to either prevent it from stripping the whitespace (without not minifying it) or if there are characters that can be used to get around the problem.

I was able to get around the issue, by validating my svg and then re-encoding it so that all the whitespace was properly encoded (base64 encoding was another option, but i opted to go with URI encoding for scripting purposes)
data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg%22%20viewBox%3D%220%200%2016%2016%22%20fill%3D%22none%22%3E%3Ccircle%20cx%3D'50%25'%20cy%3D'50%25'%20r%3D'4'%20fill%3D'blue'%20%2F%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E

